# How can i filter on column names part of which contain a value in a given list?

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this has been asked else where but i couldn't find the relevant question if there was. I have a list of values e.g.:

```
codes = [6757,1234, 5674, 9990,1110,5678,4532,1123,3456,7865]
```

i then have colnames such as:

`col1_6757, col_1234, col1_5432, col1_1110, amount_1110,` etc

I would like to filter on the pandas dataframe such that i only retrieve those colnames that contain the values in code list..

i've tried:

```
data.loc[:, data.columns.str.contains(codes)]
```

but i get the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. How can i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to strings and join by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
data.loc[:, data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(map(str, codes)))]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
data.filter(regex='|'.join(map(str, codes)))
```